# Ember JS - Normalizing Facebook Graph API

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on an Ember application that aggregates content from Facebook's Graph API and Rails API.  Since I wrote the Rails API and have control over the JSON format, I've had no issues getting my Ember application to query and serve that content.  However, I am having some difficulty normalizing the Facebook Graph API content.

As an example, here's some of the Feed JSON that the Facebook API serves:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "604231966385537_765079483634117",
         "type": "link",
         "message": "They're watching you...",
         "from": {
             "name": "Kristian Twombly",
             "id": "10154089935544635"
         }
    },
    {
         "id": "604231966385537_765057943636271",
         "type": "status",
         "message": "The boss's new ride. He saw mine and had to have one.",
         "from": {
            "name": "Walter Johnson",
            "id": "10206908914060788"
         }
    },
    {
     "id": "604231966385537_764751447000254",
     "type": "photo",
     "message": "Found 1 at Target Apple Valley",
     "from": {
        "name": "Quentin Waterkamp",
        "id": "10210042929332132"
     },
     "comments": {
        "data": [
           {
              "created_time": "2016-09-01T01:33:55+0000",
              "from": {
                 "name": "Riley Richardson",
                 "id": "1189835384423610"
              },
              "message": "Are these rare to find or something?",
              "id": "764829800325752"
           },
           {
              "created_time": "2016-09-01T04:33:44+0000",
              "from": {
                 "name": "Quentin Waterkamp",
                 "id": "10210042929332132"
              },
              "message": "seems to be I was also at a Walmart today and didn't see one and the other Target in Apple Valley didn't have any the other day.",
              "id": "764893193652746"
           }
        ],
        "paging": {
           "cursors": {
              "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOelkwT0RJNU9EQXdNekkxTnpVeU9qRTBOekkyT1RNMk16VT0ZD",
              "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZAOelkwT0Rrek1Ua3pOalV5TnpRMk9qRTBOekkzTURRME1qUT0ZD"
           }
        }
      },
    }
],
"paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/604231966385537/feed?fields=id,type,message,from,comments&icon_size=16&since=1472731871&access_token=1333570303337296|ssnHtq9p3DuFAxX23XRx7Dc1reQ&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdBfsb6FAxWTzuRVAHs3OujbQ3O0Ry2z7QIHq40E45FaLZAyf2mYy888ZASAEiw7D0N31xuAij5ZBsYVZBeVPZAXz5HfDAN2ZAklhsRHRjMu7qLzdODgZDZD&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/604231966385537/feed?fields=id,type,message,from,comments&icon_size=16&access_token=1333570303337296|ssnHtq9p3DuFAxX23XRx7Dc1reQ&limit=25&until=1472348927&__paging_token=enc_AdBhRIcyqcv8ZByyC5GnCv2PfoIzySxiZCSdRw3LoOCE2gj51ZCMv9l7OPGWLcrJeHal9Tna2rhsGEul5jEzN93dBA1BXhzdgZCmOOT9y8OqDZCSh2wZDZD"
   }
}
```

Given that the root element is `data`, I originally assumed it was being served in JSON API spec.  However, the absence of an `attributes` key means the default Ember JSONAPISerializer does not work without some modification.  Conversely, the presence of the `data` key means JSONSerializer does not parse the JSON correctly either.

I've had little luck getting the JSON to serialize correctly for all objects.  If I remove the `comments` attribute on `/app/models/facebook-photo.js`, I can get the top-level objects (like Photos, Links, Statuses) populated (I confirmed this using Ember Inspector in Chrome).  However, I am unable to serialize the embedded `hasMany` relationship for `comments`.  I'm currently getting the following error when I attempt to run my Ember application:

> extractembeddedhasmany cannot read property 'id' of null

Can anyone help me understand how to correctly normalize the JSON from the Facebook API?  In addition, how can I correctly configure the `hasMany` relationship for `comments`?

---

For reference, here's my latest code (I've only included the code for `facebook-photo` for simplification):

PLEASE NOTE: I'm using the `modelNameFromPayloadKey` and `payloadKeyFromModelName` serializer methods already, since my models for the Facebook API have 'facebook-' appended to the type name (model names were conflicting with my other API's types).

**/app/routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            facebookFeedObjects: this.get('store').query('facebook-feed', {
                fields: 'id,type,message,from,comments',
                access_token: '1333570303337296%7CssnHtq9p3DuFAxX23XRx7Dc1reQ'
            })
        });
    }
});
```

**/app/adapters/facebook-feed.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7',
    namespace: '604231966385537',
    pathForType: function(type) {
        return 'feed';
    }
});
```

**/app/models/facebook-photo.js:**

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
    message: attr(),
    comments: hasMany('facebook-comment', { polymorphic: true })
});
```

**/app/serializers/facebook-feed.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    modelNameFromPayloadKey(key) {
        let withPrefix = 'facebook-' + key;
        return this._super(withPrefix);
    },

    payloadKeyFromModelName(modelName) {
        let type = this._super(modelName);
        return `${type.replace('facebook-', '')}`;
    }
});
```

**/app/serializers/facebook-photo.js:**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    modelNameFromPayloadKey(key) {
        let withPrefix = 'facebook-' + key;
        return this._super(withPrefix);
    },

    payloadKeyFromModelName(modelName) {
        let type = this._super(modelName);
        return `${type.replace('facebook-', '')}`;
    },

    attrs: {
        comments: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
});
```

**/app/templates/index.hbs:**

```
<h3>Facebook</h3>
<ul>
    {{#each model.facebookFeedObjects as |obj|}}
        <li>      
            <h4>{{obj.message}}</h4>
            <ul>
                {{#each obj.comments as |comment|}}
                    <li>{{comment}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is going to be to write your [own custom serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/models/customizing-serializers/). Something similar to this:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  serialize(snapshot, options) {
    var json = this._super(...arguments);

    json.data.attributes.message = json.data.message;
    json.data.attributes.from = {
      name: json.data.from.name,
      id: json.data.from.id
    }

    delete json.data.message;
    delete json.data.from

    return json;
  },
});
```

Note that this doesn't take into account the **comments** field, but you should be able to do something similar to build out the relationships to adhere to [JSON API format](http://jsonapi.org/format/).